# QPrinter::metric: Invalid metric command (when print html document of QTextedit)

Tags: qt, printing

When I want to print the doc(html) of QTextedit,like:

```
ted = new QTextDocument();
printer=new QPrinter();
printer->setOutputFormat(QPrinter::NativeFormat);
printer->setPaperSize(QPrinter::A4);
ted->setHtml(QString("<img src=\"D:\\Penguins.jpg\" width=\"200\" height=\"200\" />"));
ted->print(printer);
```

And I got debug warning:

> QPrinter::metric: Invalid metric command

But when html do not have img tag,like "`<b>bold</b>`",no warning output.

why?

Comment: Thew code you shared does not set your QPrinter object to a printer in your system?

Comment: @MohammadKanan ,Thank you for your reply,and how do I set it?I think it might not be necessary.

Comment: Are you printing to real hardware printer? then set your object to that printer for example `printer=new QPrinter(QPrinterInfo::defaultPrinter());`

Comment: @MohammadKanan I tried,but also got warning message. Anyway I can print by default XPS document writer printer.That's not the problem.

Comment: It can be the problem, try setting resolution to HighDI

Comment: `QPrinter::HighResolution`